# Creating vector of results of repeated function calls in R

Tags: r

I have a function that uses `runif` to calculate some value, so each time it is called, the result varies slightly. I want to calculate the mean of the result of several calls to the function.

For this, it would be great to create a vector with the results of repeated function calls

Is there a simple idiomatic way to create a vector of repeated function calls? I tries

```
rep(my_function_call(), 10)
```

but it simply calls the function once and repeats the result 10 times. I want the function evaluated 10 times, and a vector of the results.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`replicate` is your friend. See `?replicate`

```
replicate(10, my_function_call()) # this would be what you're looking for
```

Comment: Quote from manual: ``replicate is a wrapper for the common use of sapply for repeated evaluation of an expression (which will usually involve random number generation)``