# Is there a way to repeat a function a fixed number of times and save every result as a data frame?

Tags: r

let's say I have a data frame which looks something like this

```
A <- c(1:100)
B <- c(0.5:100)
df <- data.frame(A,B)
```

And I want to get 25 random rows out of this data frame with

```
df[sample(nrow(df), size = 25, replace = FALSE),]
```

But now I want to repeat this sample function 100 times and save every result individually.
I've tried to use the repeat function but I can't find a way to save every result.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the function `replicate`

Comment: You can also look into using a for loop. I agree with @camille that replicate would be the easiest.

Comment: Related posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46104176/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/13313432/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39462200/5325862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As mentioned in the comments, the `replicate` implementation can reach your goal, i.e.,

```
res <- replicate(100,df[sample(nrow(df), size = 25, replace = FALSE),],simplify = F)
```

- An alternative is to use `sapply` (or `lapply`), i.e.,

```
res <- sapply(1:100, function(k) df[sample(nrow(df), size = 25, replace = FALSE),],simplify = F)
```

or

```
res <- lapply(1:100, function(k) df[sample(nrow(df), size = 25, replace = FALSE),])
```

Answer (score 0):

`replicate()` is a great option for this problem.

If you would like your final results in a single table with a column for the ID variable, you can use `bind_rows()` from the `dplyr` package. Here is a smaller example (3 samples from a data set of 10 rows) that may allow easier understanding of `replicate()`'s behavior:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# make a smaller data set of 10 rows
d <- data.frame(
  A = 1:10,
  B = LETTERS[1:10]
) %>% print
#>     A B
#> 1   1 A
#> 2   2 B
#> 3   3 C
#> 4   4 D
#> 5   5 E
#> 6   6 F
#> 7   7 G
#> 8   8 H
#> 9   9 I
#> 10 10 J

# create 3 samples, with each sample containing 4 rows
reps <- replicate(3, d[sample(nrow(d), 4, FALSE), ], simplify = FALSE) %>% print
#> [[1]]
#>   A B
#> 2 2 B
#> 5 5 E
#> 6 6 F
#> 1 1 A
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   A B
#> 3 3 C
#> 2 2 B
#> 5 5 E
#> 8 8 H
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   A B
#> 4 4 D
#> 9 9 I
#> 3 3 C
#> 8 8 H

# bind the list elements into a single tibble, with an ID column for the sample
bind_rows(reps, .id = "sample_id")
#>    sample_id A B
#> 1          1 2 B
#> 2          1 5 E
#> 3          1 6 F
#> 4          1 1 A
#> 5          2 3 C
#> 6          2 2 B
#> 7          2 5 E
#> 8          2 8 H
#> 9          3 4 D
#> 10         3 9 I
#> 11         3 3 C
#> 12         3 8 H
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I am using ````myfun <- function(){
  df[sample(nrow(df), size = 25, replace = FALSE),]
}```` for my function right now. Is there a way to get the sum of column A in my function for every sample?

Comment: Please don't make the same comment after multiple answers. It makes it harder to track responses.